# urlManager removing index.php in yii2 doesn't work

Tags: yii2

I installed yii2 from composer and wanted to remove index.php.

I tried doing this:

in config->web.php:

```
    'urlManager' => [

        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

in web->.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I even checked if .htaccess file works by running `deny from all` and it worked, but this script doesn't or at least I dont know why.

Some stuff what I noticed:

1. When I enable `'showScriptName' => false,` footer of the page doesn't show up
   [image: My webapp bottom of the page]
2. When I try to open midori.dev/web/site/index it shows:

   Object not found!

   The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL      manually please check your spelling and try again.

   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

   Error 404

   midori.dev.lv
   Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

ps. I have configured hosts file and vhost file for `midori.dev` instead of localhost.

Where is the issue?

Comment: Why you are including `web` in url? Try `midori.dev/site/index`.

Comment: Because after default installation its part of website url. That I will try to change after this.

Comment: Where you saw this as a part of website url? `web` it's just web-accessible folder with the entry script `index.php`.

Comment: If I don't type in ...web/... I can't get any results at all.

Comment: What appears on the screen in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux

change httpd.conf file

AllowOverride All

if you create a virtual host,
your file should look like this

DocumentRoot "/path/to/web"

RewriteEngine on

```
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# ...other settings...
```

Comment: I'm using windows 8, but I did it as well.